# How to store a value only for a certain period in tomcat/java

Tags: java, caching, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to store some values only for certain period of time in a collection in tomcat java web application.

The scenario is :

- `value1` is added first
- `value2` is added 1 minute after `value1`
- `value3` is added just after `value2` is added
- `value4` is added 2 minute after `value1` is added

This values should be available only for 5 minute time after they added. After 5 minute they should be removed from the list.
Every value expires after 5 minute time (after they added) regardless of their last access time.

I have already started to implement this by using a `ConcurrentHashMap` and `ScheduledExecutor`.

I could not find a proper in-built cache mechanism for this requirement and if a cache is used it will not remove/expire the values from the list if values are accessed more frequently.

I appreciate if someone can give me a direction or reference to any existing implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it manually here's a simple idea :

1. Create a class that wraps the type you want to store with a date.
2. Extend `HashMap`, overriding the `get()` method so that it checks
       the date, returns `null` if the date is too old, and returns the object stored
       otherwise.

EDIT:

If memory is a problem, you can iterate the map to remove expired values every X minute. To do so, in the overriden `get()` method check last cleanup date, if it was more than X minutes ago do cleanup now. But if you don't have memory issues you may even skip this.

Comment: What about the cleanup policy ?

Answer (score 3):

[google guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) can do that(very simple)

```
com.google.common.cache.Cache<Integer, String> values = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().concurrencyLevel(4).expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).maximumSize(20).build();        

values.put(someKey, "string val");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a collection delivered with java.util.*.

One option is to to guava's [Cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html). Instances can be created via [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html). In your case most interesting method is [expireAfterWrite](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterWrite%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

Answer (score 0):

IF you are talking about storing the values for each client cookies can be used for this.

Comment: No. The requirement is in the server side.